# Badge Not count after I kill app and rerun swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, notifications, swift4

I am working with notification. and I count all notification that received to create a badge. but it seems not count after I kill the app and re-run it in background mode. Could anyone help me? Thank

Answer (score 0):

You cannot process notifications when your app is in background or killed. Unless you implement [UNNotificationServiceExtension](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationserviceextension)

Comment: This might not what i want. I mean, after I rerun my app, I cannot count the badage anymore, .

Answer (score 0):

You should read [Local and Push Notification Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/APNSOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH8-SW1) and especially the The [Notification Payload](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/PayloadKeyReference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH17-SW1).

The payload could look like this:

```
{
    "aps" : {
        "alert" : "You have a new message",
        "badge" : 3
    }
}
```

Now the application badge icon will show 3.

Comment: That will take server work right? they have to count it everytime.

Comment: Yes get badge count from server

Comment: is there another way to set it?

Comment: I think no. In iOS not possible to do anything when application is kill. It may be that way which i told you

Comment: not when it kill, when it in background. at first , I can count all data in background. but after i killed it and try to run it again, it not work anymore in background